# PHP indexing documents in elasticsearch won't accept timestamp

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am inserting a simple document in elasticSearch using PHP. 
The document is inserted but unfortunately the timestamp is not recorded, and no time stamp is added automatically.

here is a sample code :

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
use Carbon\Carbon;

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $firstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
      $lastName = $_POST['LastName']; 
      $address = $_POST['Address']; 

      $hosts = [
          'http://localhost:9200'
      ];
      $client = ClientBuilder::create()           // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
                          ->setHosts($hosts)      // Set the hosts
                          ->build();              // Build the client object



      $myDateTime=Carbon::now();
      $params = [
          'index' => 'auditsvilles',
          'type' => 'logs',
          'id' => 'id0001',
          'timestamp' => $myDateTime->toIso8601String(),
          'body' => ['FirstName' => $firstName, 'LastName' => $lastName]
      ];

      $response = $client->index($params);
      print_r($response);
  }
?>
```

I have searched quite extensively, and found someinputs about using Iso8601, but it didn't change.

Comment: Do you want it to be stored as epoch?

Comment: When you are indexing the docs, you can have a look at the elastic log. It should lend you a hint if there's a problem with your document/date field.

Comment: In the deprecation log there is this line : The [timestamp] parameter of index requests is deprecated it is quite frustrating as I am following the example provided by elasticsearch [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_indexing_documents.html)

Comment: Any format is fine for me as lon as there is a timestamp which is required by most tools accessing elastic search documents (like kibana)

Comment: Ok, it seems that putting a '@timestamp' param in 'body' is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting a '@timestamp' param in 'body' is what I need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).